# Line/Unlike - same number?

Tags: facebook-like

We made a fan research about our facebook page of music band.

It´s about 6 months and new fans are adding throught the LIKE button there, but there is almost the same number of unlike according to this so it has an impact on total likes on the page, where it is still about the same numerical value (at about 13.045 or less/more in tens). Today we received feedbacks from our fans, they don´t know why they aren´t still counted in Like button, so they must again click on it.

Is there any problem in setting or how can we deal with it?

Thanking you in advance for your help!